# Importações dentro de funções no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, importação

Já vi casos em que o desenvolvedor faz a importação de um módulo dentro de uma função, alguns casos principalmente na documentação do Django, o porquê disso não ficou muito claro pra mim, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem 2 razões para o desenvolvedor fazer isso:

1. Performance - A importação vai acontecer apenas quando a função for chamada, e caso ela nunca seja chamada, o interpretador não irá precisar carregar o módulo.
2. Retrocompatibilidade - A bibliotecas importadas podem ser necessárias apenas em ambientes específicos (exemplo Windows vs Linux, Python 2 vs Python 3). O sistema pode chamar a função especifica pra cada ambiente e nela carregar as bibliotecas compatíveis.

Comment: Obrigado Begnini.

Comment: Na verdade, há mais um motivo que é "evitar importações circulares" - isso é, o código da função no módulo A precisa acessar atributos ou funções que estão num módulo B que por sua vez importa (direta ou indiretamente) o módulo A. Dessa forma, isso evita que uma referência ao módulo B incompleta esteja disponível durante a importação do módulo A - e, durante a execução das funções de A, uma vez que B ja está na memória, os imports tem apenas o mesmo impacto de uma associação de variável (isso é: não implicam em achar e compilar o arquivo do disco)